# TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined when asking for confirmation

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have made a command which locks and unlocks a channel by changing the send permissions of the role that is mentioned. After you execute the command, it asks for confirmation by you typing 'yes' in the chat. However, if you do not type yes, you get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
```

Here is the code:

```js
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`)) return message.reply('I lack the required permissions to run this command. (Required Permissions: ``MANAGE_CHANNELS``)');          
        if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")){
            const channel = message.channel;
            
            const Discord = require("discord.js");
            let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args.join(" "));
            if(!role){
                message.reply("please mention a role.")
            } else{
                message.reply('Are you sure you want to continue this command, it will disallow send permissions from the role you mentioned. Type ``yes`` to continue.')
                let filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id
                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000}).then(collected => {           
                    if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() !== 'yes') return;
                    try {
                        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                    .setTitle("Channel Locked")
                                    .setColor("RED")
                                    .setDescription(`Channel locked to the specified role`)
                    
                                    message.channel.updateOverwrite(role, {
                                        SEND_MESSAGES: false
                                    })
                                    .then(channel => channel.send(embed))
                                    .catch(console.error)
                    }
                    catch(error) {
                        message.reply("Command either timed out or there was an error.")
                    }
                    })   
            }
                
        }
```

Someone suggested to use try and catch, but either this did not help or I did it wrong. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Apparently `collected.first()` is `undefined`, so check for that first.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks it worked :D

Comment: If your Question has been solved, please mark an answer as the accepted solution using the Green Tick, that will mark the Question as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `if (collected.size && collected.first().content.toLowerCase() !== 'yes')`, this checks if if collected.size is not 0.

Otherwise the approch of `if (collected.first() && collected.first().content.toLowerCase() !== 'yes')` would also work.